# Test if an e-mail account works using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to log into an e-mail account to which I have the username and password and see if the user used the correct password. How does one do that?

Comment: What line is the error showing in your code?

Comment: Waaaay too broad a question. What kind of email account? How do you propose to get the user's user/pw? Will making a general interface to any email account, or just (say) gmail? POP mailbox? IMAP? Exchange? Notes? Before you start picking out the colors you want the walls to be, how about deciding if the house should have walls first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php